# How to correctly select data from LINQ to Entities expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two entities: Document and Attachment. One document might have several or no Attachments. I need to receive an IQueryable that will allow me to always select entries both for document and all of its attachments.

Here is the initial query but it selects only Attachments. For example, if I have 1 doc with 2 attachments it will select 2 entries, but I need to have 1 + 2 = 3 entries in this case.

```
from d in Documents
from at in Attachments.Where(a=>a.DocumentID == d.ID).DefaultIfEmpty(null)
where d.StatusID != -1 && d.ID == 1
select new Result { ID = d.ID, AttachID = at?.ID };
```

Currently I will receive pure Document entry only if it don't have any attachments. Is it possible to always include additional entry for Document even if it has some attachments?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Linq To SQL? It is a obsolete a long time now. Maybe you're talking about Linq To Entities with EF?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've corrected the topic

Answer (score 1):

You can (left-)join documents and their attachments:

```
var q = from d in Documents.Where(doc => doc.StatusID != -1 && doc.ID == 1)
        join a in Attachments
        on d.ID equals a.DocumentID  into docAtt
        from att in docAtt.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new Result { ID = d.ID, AttachID = att?.ID };
```

Comment: Sorry, I was getting the same results with this query. Solved by using two queries and Concat method (equivalent to UNION).

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Documents.Where(d => d.ID == 1 && d.StatusID != -1)
                      .GroupJoin(Attachments, d => d.ID, a => a.DocumentID,
                      (d, matchedAttachments) =>
                      {
                          //here you can do whatever with document and list of corresponding matched attachments
                          return matchedAttachments.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(ma => new Result { ID = d.ID, AttachID = ma?.ID });
                      });
```